# Is a UV Sphere with a glass shader applied to it considered to be a shell of glass or a solid sphere of glass in Blender Cycles?

Tags: glass, photorealism

I have been confused by this aspect. I am trying to create a solid sphere of glass and I'm worried about the light not refracting and transmitting realistically like a real sphere of solid glass. What I would like to know is if a UV sphere with a *Glass BSDF* shader is considered to be a glass shell by Blender or if it is considered a solid sphere of glass?

If it is the former, how can I create a realistic solid ball of glass that refracts and reflects light like a solid glass ball IRL?

Comment: Spheres are considered solid (a filled medium) until you give the outer edges some thickness (2 sided walls). This can be most easily accomplished by using a Solidify Modifier. If you want to keep it solid, leave it "empty" (untouched). Also - Making a solid glass ball that refracts properly only really works in Cycles - It can be approximated in EEVEE, but it never really looks correct and the refractions will never be "physically accurate".

Comment: Hi :). To illustrate - a UV sphere will refract light first when it *enters*, and then second time when it *leaves* the geometry. Exactly like a solid glass ball.

Comment: @JachymMichal So the inside of the sphere in Blender is not considered to be 'air' or a 'vacuum'?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett So a sphere with solidify modifier is considered to be shell like? But what if I wanted the outer edges to have some extra thickness AND have the inside be solid as well?

Comment: Usually, the "thickness" can be controlled by the IOR of the glass material.

Comment: @Hash If you want the outer edges to have thickness and have a solid sphere inside, then maybe that's exactly what you should do - create an outside sphere that has a thickness, e.g. with the _Solidify Modifier_, then put a smaller sphere inside without the modifier so that it's a solid sphere. Or I simply don't get what you want... to me it sounds like you want a solid glass ball that's stuck inside a hollow glass ball...?

Comment: it looks like in Eevee, a full sphere (closed), an open sphere (with no thickness, just delete one face) and a sphere with thickness (for example with Solidify) give the exact same result, in Cycles only thickness seems to make difference. As Christopher says you probably need to play with IOR to make a difference if you don't see enough.

Comment: @moonboots That's because in Eevee glass thickness is defined through material settings, not the actual geometry :)

Comment: yes ok good to know  ;)

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I'm confused. I recall seeing lists of PBR iors for common materials out there. If I change the ior, is it not no longer realistic to what glass really refract light irl then?

Comment: 1.450 is generally regarded as the "appropriate" IOR for glass, but since you have special requirements (ie thick walls) it might be in order to "cheat" the rules a little. The other option is to do as others have suggested and place a hollow glass sphere inside a solid glass "shell".

Comment: Just wanted to add: While refraction-wise, the glass shader creates a solid, the *colour* of the glass shader is like *surface* painted glass. I.e., for coloured glass you want to use volume shading

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just to illustrate how Cycles treats these cases:

**Left:** Sphere walls with zero thickness (light refracts twice) > behaves like a solid glass ball
**Right:** Sphere walls with 1 mm thickness (light refracts four times) > behaves like a soap bubble

[image]
[image]

Comment: If i were to model a glass cup glass cup, the only way to do that would be to create a cylinder shaped object and solidify it by making its thickness nonzero. Won't that make it similar to a 'bubble' then rather than a solid glass cup? And does the second picture look like a bubble because the thickness is so low, the deviation of the refracted rays is almost nil?

Comment: No, what I meant was the glass being a 'thick' cylinder with a hole in the middle rather than a thin cylinder with a hole in the middle to make a cup? Would the former, according to your diagram result in a thin bubble like 'glass' during render as opposed to realistic glass?

Comment: What I mean is something like this. Lets say I take a cylinder, inset the top face and delete it, and scale down the bottom face to make a 'cup'. Like a frustrum with one end open

Now such a cylinder would have 0 thickness unless I use a solidify modifier. But you stated that having non zero thickness would make cycles treat the object like a 'shell'. 

But a non-solidified frustrum cup would look ugly and thin. So how do I get it behave like a real glass frustrum cup with thickness, but at the same time not act like a 'shell' frustrum cup?

Comment: Hello :). I'm obviously not very good at explaining things. So here's [BlenderGuru's Glass Cup tutorial](https://youtu.be/7a0cHFs7jkw). Look at his model, that's how it should look. There's no caveat. Just model it like a real cup :)).

Comment: In the video, he models it using a solidify modifier or in other words, with non-zero thickness. Isnt that equivalent to a 'shell-like' glass according to your diagram?

Comment: Yes, that's what you want for a glass cup or a glass bottle :)

Comment: So essentially the 'solidified' part are solid, but everything inside the solidified region is considered to be empty?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: I understand now! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you just create a sphere, it is treated as a solid. It is easy to determine what is inside and outside the sphere. But if you remove a bunch of faces, you break this behaviour. It is no longer easy to determine the inside and outside.

Here is a solid sphere with a glass material. It has a high refracture index. It will actually focus light from the light source onto the plane it is resting. But this is quite noisy. I have switched the renderer to **Cycles**.

It actually have a tiny highlight from the light source. This is because it has a very low roughness but also that the light source is very small. Change to an area light and make it bigger.

[image]

With this 2D sketch I try to explain how non-solid objects work.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). I'm not sure the first paragraph is correct. Refraction angle is specified by normals orientation. Having some faces missing doesn't play a role :).

Comment: If a ray goes in through a surface and exits through a hole, where does cycles consider the sphere to stop?

Comment: Hey :). The ray will be refracted only once. However, you can always tell what's inside/outside, because that's specified by normals orientation (which will affect the refraction angle). Feel free to correct me, my brain is running on fumes right now :))

Comment: Ok, I think we mean different things. I will try to clarify my answer, no time right now. When it enters the sphere through a face, it will be inside. But if it exits through a hole, cycles will count it as forever being inside the sphere.

Comment: @JachymMichal it took a while, check my sketch and see if you agree.

Comment: Hey, that diagram is really sweet, +1 from me ;)